# Dialogflow Context Disjunction

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is it possible some how to assign a Dialogflow intent to contexts with disjunction union.
I.e. I need an intent Test<A | B> to be triggered whatever single of contexts A or B are being active even if solely.

Since I don't want to duplicate a whole the intent with the only difference in theses context references.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment, but you can open a Feature Request by following [this link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).